# Lua - associate function with object's parameter

Tags: lua

I'm trying to do an easy exercise for WoW's client.

I have the next object:

```
local name = detailsFrame:CreateFontString("$name", "ARTWORK", "Fancy24Font")
name.SetFontObjects = MySetFontObjects;
```

Where the function MySetFontObjects is the next one:

```
function MySetFontObjects (self, ...) {
    self.fontObjects = { ... };
    --more stuff
}
```

If I try to call that function it returns `attempt to call a method 'MySetFontObjects' (a nil value)`

I'm calling it like this:

```
name:SetFontObjects(Font1, Font2, Font3);
```

What am I doing wrong? I just don't see it.

Comment: `name.SetFontObjects = MySetFontObjects`, you're setting `SetFontObjects`, but then calling `MySetFontObjects`. It's not there, call `SetFontObjects` instead.

Comment: That was actually a mistake after transcribing the question. In my real example  the name matches (it's just a longer one in spanish)

Comment: Your function MySetFontObjects is a syntax error in Lua. It should be `function MySetFontObjects (self, ...) ... end`, not `function MySetFontObjects (self, ...) { ... }`. Could you post your actual code? Then we can see what's actually wrong with it. :) It's fine if it's in Spanish - the logic itself doesn't change, so most contributors here should be able to spot the bugs even if they don't speak Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing something like this?

```
local name = {}
name.SetFontObjects = MySetFontObjects

function MySetFontObjects (self, ...)
    self.fontObjects = { ... }
    --more stuff
end

name:SetFontObjects("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

This produces the "attempt to call method 'SetFontObjects' (a nil value)" error that you seem to be reporting.

This happens because when you set `name.SetFontObjects = MySetFontObjects`, the `MySetFontObjects` function is not yet defined, so `MySetFontObjects` defaults to a global variable with a value of `nil`. To fix this, just move the function definition above that statement:

```
function MySetFontObjects (self, ...)
    self.fontObjects = { ... }
    --more stuff
end

local name = {}
name.SetFontObjects = MySetFontObjects

name:SetFontObjects("foo", "bar", "baz")
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm at work right not, but I definetly have my function definition after that statement, so that might be the problem. I will let you know if that solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: That was it! thanks! once I moved the function above it worked!